# How to extract key types in dart map?

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, types

Is there any solution for extracting key types in dart?

In typescript, we could use `typeof keyof` to accomplish this.

https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/09/typescript-keyof-typeof-with-code-examples.html

[More explanation] - Edited

I was trying to achieve the way of using static types with Map in Flutter.
In typescript, you could see typed keys with autocompletion using `typeof keyof`. Below is an example when using i18next.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27461460/197675436-041f13bd-bdb1-4b5a-b748-0f0cd54879b3.png

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what you mean (the static type? or the runtime type?) and on what you intend to do?  While you could extract either the static type or the runtime type for a `Map`'s keys, there isn't much useful you could actually do with it afterward.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for responding to this. I really appreciate this.

I was trying to achieve the way of using static types with Map in Flutter.
In typescript, you could see typed keys with autocompletion using `typeof keyof`. Below is an example when using i18next.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27461460/197675436-041f13bd-bdb1-4b5a-b748-0f0cd54879b3.png

Please give me more feedback if this isn't clear enough to you

Comment: A Dart `Map` is a homogeneous collection that has a single static type for its keys and a single static type for its values.  In JavaScript (and thus TypeScript), objects are equivalent to dictionaries; one is syntactic sugar for the other.  In Dart, if you want separate types for separate "keys", you should declare a class and with explicitly typed member variables instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks I just wanted to clarify that there is no way to automatize this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you mean.

```
main() {

  var mapi = {
    'key' : 12,
  };
  
  print(mapi.values.runtimeType.toString());
}
```

if you replace `values` with `keys` then the output will give you

```
LinkedHashMapKeyIterable<String>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for trying to answer my question.
I've just added more description to the question.
This example is still checking key values in runtime.